# References on how to embed python classes/functions in C++ using BoostPython

Tags: boost-python

May I know, if I can refer to some good website references/links that show how I can embed/wrap python classes and functions(methods) in C++(not the other way around). I found how to wrap from C++ to python([like here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html)), but what I'm interested in, is the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call C++ from Python. The tutorial you pointed out contains an introduction to that. Look for the section "Functions - Overloading". It shows how you can create bindings to allow your C++ call pythonic functions. The approach can also be applied to classes.